# Need to access variable x with value 5 in else portion

Tags: c++, if-statement, scope

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    if(0) {
    }
    else if(int x = 0) {
    }
    else {
    cout << "I want to access variable x with value 5";
    }
}
```

Here variable x defined in else if will be available in else block also, but if I need to access the variable defined in main then how to go about it.

Comment: `Here variable x defined in else if will be available in else block also` Are you sure?

Comment: Why are you writing crap code?

Comment: Hey, wait, it does.. what http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3bd260584fd85b0

Comment: Would be interesting to see how you intend to use this madness

Comment: 6.4/3 .. learn something new every year

Comment: That's easy: rename at least one of them.

Comment: Surely, this combination of hiding a variable with initializing it within a boolean expression can only be an attempt at obfuscation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible, the inner x hides the outer one. I assume the compiler will warn you about that, at least with `pedantic` and depending on the comipler.